# Crop and extract text from PDF

Tags: pdf, text, extract, crop

I have cropped a PDF using the following command.

```
gswin32c.exe ^
-o cropped.pdf ^
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite ^
-c "[/CropBox [64 418 348 803] /PAGE pdfmark" ^
-f original.pdf
```

The PDF is getting cropped. I used the following command to extract the text from the cropped PDF.

```
gswin32c.exe ^
-q ^
-sFONTPATH=c:/windows/fonts ^
-dNODISPLAY ^
-dSAFER ^
-dDELAYBIND ^
-dWRITESYSTEMDICT ^
-dSIMPLE ^
-f ps2ascii.ps ^
-dFirstPage=1 ^
-dLastPage=1 ^
cropped.pdf ^
-> c:\output.txt ^
-dQUIET
```

The output contains the text of the original PDF and not the cropped PDF.

Can someone help to extract the text only from the cropped PDF.

Thanks
Nazeer

Answer (score 2):

The result you got is exactly what is to be expected.

- *Cropping* of a PDF page does ***NOT*** mean: cut off everything around the cropped area and delete it.
- Cropping means: do only display what's inside the cropped area (and zoom to it), and hide what's around it.

So when you convert such a page to text, you'll also get the hidden content back.

Comment: Is there a way to remove hidden content as well?

Answer (score 0):

You may be more lucky, if you try a different means to convert the cropped.pdf to text:

> ***Open it in Acrobat/Adobe Reader.***
>
> ***Click 'File --> Save as Text...'***